# Where can I find a .iso for Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, iso-image

I need to test a program on Windows XP, where can I find a .iso to put on a VM? Is there any way to get an iso similar to what microsoft hosts on [Their Website](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/), a free .iso that expires after 90 days for development use.

Comment: @Arjan, there is no longer a relevant answer on that old thread.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but I vaguely recall a so-called "Windows XP Mode for Windows 7", and what it actually was was an XP in a virtual machine - I don't recall the details, but here's a link  where you should be able to download it:

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8002

The description from MS
"

> Windows XP Mode for Windows 7 makes it easy to install and run many of your productivity programs that run on Windows XP directly from a computer that runs Windows 7.
>
> Windows XP Mode provides a 32-bit virtual Windows XP Professional Service Pack 3 (SP3) environment. This download includes a virtual hard disk (.vhd file) with Windows XP SP3 preinstalled. Client virtualization software, such as Windows Virtual PC is required to use Windows XP Mode.

"

This link mentions it too:

https://zeltser.com/windows-xp-mode-for-vmware-virtualization/

But the main thing is that microsoft.com link with the download.

Answer (score 0):

Though I have not tried this myself, [Offline Installers](http://offlineinstallersoft.blogspot.com/2015/03/windows-xp-pro-sp3-iso-download-free.html) states [a link](http://dreamsupport.us/downloads/windows-pc/-WindowsXP/Microsoft.Windows.XP.Professional.SP3.Integrated6-11.iso) will deliver the full XP sp-3 Pro ISO. Login to download is provided at Offline Installers. *Caveat downloador*, as they say in igpay atinlay.

You might be better served downloading a more recent OS ISO, as [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/186775/how-to-download-windows-7-8-and-8.1-installation-media-legally/) describes.